# How to return a list of values from a filtered column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'd like to return a list of visible values (including zeroes) from a filtered column from one sheet into an another one so that the list will update if a new value is added into the original dataset and if it matches the selected filter.

Example of unfiltered data:

| A/B | VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 0 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 3 |
| B | 0 |
| B | -1 |
| A | 4 |
| B | -5 |
| A | 1 |
| B | 4 |

Then if I filter for "B", the output in a new sheet should be (the header is not needed):

```
0
3
0
-1
-5
4
```

I've tried this formula

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B1000;(SUBTOTAL(109;OFFSET(Sheet1!B2:B1000;ROW(Sheet1!B2:B1000)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!B2:B1000));;1))))
```

but it omits the zero values, so I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: With your existing formula it will be like: `=FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B1000;(SUBTOTAL(103;OFFSET(Sheet1!A2:A1000;ROW(Sheet1!A2:A1000)-MIN(ROW(Sheet1!A2:A1000));;1))))` instead of column `B` it should be column `A` the one on which the filter will be applied and instead of `109` it will be `103`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try one of the followings:

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D13</kbd> using `LAMBDA()` helper function `MAP()` with `SUBTOTAL()` and `FILTER()` funtions.

---

```
=FILTER(B2:B11,MAP(A2:A11,LAMBDA(x,SUBTOTAL(103,x))))
```

---

• Or, Using `LET()` with `FILTER()`, `SUBTOTAL()` and `SEQUENCE()` functions:

```
=LET(x, A2:A11, FILTER(B2:B11,SUBTOTAL(103,OFFSET(x,SEQUENCE(ROWS(x))-1,0,1))))
```

---

[image]

---

**Notes:** Please change the separators as per your regional locale settings, as well as change the cell reference and ranges accordingly as per your suit.

---

Comment: I've tried this function that you've suggested `=FILTER(B2:B11,MAP(A2:A11,LAMBDA(x,SUBTOTAL(103,x))))` but I've replaced the A2:A11 range with B2:B11 and now the function works even if I filter a different column than A (my sheet has more columns that my example here), but I can still get values from the column B. Thanks for help.